# Errors when running SSL with grunt server

Tags: ssl, gruntjs, yeoman

I am working on yeoman based angular.js app.

We have set up the gruntfile to run over https.

It works fine on my workmates machine but not on mine.

In Chrome I get:

```
SSL connection error. 
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. 
This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
```

In Firefox I get:

```
The connection was interrupted
The connection to localhost:9000 was interrupted while the page was loading.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I have double checked we have the same npm modules installed.

Relevant parts of gruntfile are

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'https',
    key: grunt.file.read('server.key').toString(),
    cert: grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString(),
    ca: grunt.file.read('ca.crt').toString(),
    passphrase: 'grunt',


  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      protocol: 'https',
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          modRewrite([
            '^/api/(.*) /api/index.php?$1 [L]',
            '!\\.html|\\.js|\\.php|\\.css|\\.png$ /index.html [L]'
          ]),
          lrSnippet,
          phpGateway('app'),

          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

my workmate generated the certificate files, but that shouldn't matter as I have exact copies of those files.

The strangest part is that I can still run the site over http where on my workmates machine it won't run over http at all, only https.

Is there anything else anyone can think of as to why this would be?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did and gave up.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error "This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have" and the fact that it runs on your friend's computer but not yours leads me to believe that it's a problem with the SSL keys and certificate on your computer. You can generate your own using the tutorial here: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

```
key: grunt.file.read('server.key').toString(),
cert: grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString(),
ca: grunt.file.read('ca.crt').toString()
```

Make sure that the above files are in your base folder from which you are running grunt. The ca.crt file is also necessary for self-signing your own certificate using a certificate authority that you create using the tutorial above. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would first look for the log file and tail that as you're making the request. It might give you hints as to what is wrong

Comment: Ok, sorry to sound dumb but where would I find a log file for this??

Comment: i'm not familiar with this environment, but is there a local tmp/ or log/ directory you can look in? or is it sending output to the screen?